# Hub Status When IIS is Stop or Restart Doesn't Work

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Hub Status when project in IIS stop or restart hub it doesn't change but when application pool stop hub is stop and its ok but I need when IIS restart clients in signalr are understand server is not alive
I use asp.net framework 4.8 how to fix that in angular js and use signalr 2.4
I have a queue system using SignalR 2.1.1 with Angular. Everything is working perfectly actually. However when I decided to test the system against an IIS outage I noticed a problem. When I stop, then start IIS, IIS restart doesn't cause the issue, my javascript functions that the hub calls will no longer fire. That makes sense to me, but the problem is that the client can still call the server without any issue so the user has no idea they are disconnected. This would certainly mess up my queue state

```
public class OwinStartup
{
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration();
hubConfiguration.EnableDetailedErrors = true;

            // Any connection or hub wire up and configuration should go here
            app.MapSignalR(hubConfiguration);
        }
    }



and this is my Global.asax => 
  public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

            IocConfigure();

            DataAccess.Configuration.Init();
            Abomis.Dcs.Web.Utility.EmailSettingProvider.Init(null);

            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            MvcHandler.DisableMvcResponseHeader = true; //this line is to hide mvc header in http response

        }

        private void IocConfigure()
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

            // Register MVC controllers
            builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly);

            // Register all services from Abomis.Dcs.Domain project
            var repositories = Assembly.Load("Abomis.Dcs.DataAccess");
            builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(repositories)
                .Where(i => i.Name.EndsWith("Repository"))
                .AsImplementedInterfaces()
                .WithParameter("connectionString", Utility.ConnectionStringProvider.Get())
                .InstancePerRequest();

            builder.RegisterType<TokenProvider>().As<ITokenProvider>()
                .InstancePerRequest();


            builder.Register(c => new AuthenticationFilterAttribute(c.Resolve<ITokenProvider>()))
                .InstancePerRequest();

            builder.RegisterFilterProvider();


            // Set the dependency resolver to be Autofac.
            var container = builder.Build();
            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
        }

        public void ErrorLog_Filtering(Object sender, ExceptionFilterEventArgs args)
        {
            var httpContext = args.Context as HttpContext;
            if (httpContext != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    var error = new Error(args.Exception, httpContext);
                    string spTitle = "";
                    try { spTitle = ((System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException)httpContext.AllErrors[0]).Procedure; } catch { }
                    var sp = error.Source == ".Net SqlClient Data Provider" && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(spTitle) ? $" (SP: {spTitle})" : "";

                    //save username
                    try
                    {
                        var user = new TokenProvider().IdentityUser;
                        if (user != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.UserName.Trim()))
                        {
                            error.User = user.UserName;
                            error.Detail = error.Detail.Insert(0, $"Username: {user.UserName}\r\n");
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex) { }

                    //save request body
                    try
                    {
                        var bodyStream = new System.IO.StreamReader(httpContext.Request.InputStream);
                        bodyStream.BaseStream.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
                        var bodyText = bodyStream.ReadToEnd();
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(bodyText))
                        {
                            error.Detail = error.Detail.Insert(0, $"RequestBody: {bodyText}\r\n");
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    { }

                    error.Message += sp;

                    ErrorLog.GetDefault(httpContext).Log(error);
                    args.Dismiss();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                { }
            }
        }

        protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var app = sender as HttpApplication;
            if (app != null && app.Context != null)
            {
                app.Context.Response.Headers.Remove("Server");
                app.Context.Response.Headers.Add("X-Frame-Options", "SAMEORIGIN");//DENY
                app.Context.Response.Headers.Add("X-XSS-Protection", "1");
                app.Context.Response.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
                app.Context.Response.Cache.AppendCacheExtension("no-store");
            }
        }

        protected void Session_start(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var c = new HttpCookie("PrintDynamicPort")
            {
                Name = "PrintDynamicPort",
                Value = null,
                HttpOnly = true,
                Secure = Request.IsSecureConnection
                //SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict
            };
            HttpContext.Current.Response.SetCookie(c);
        }
    }
```